# 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Animation'

Tags: xamarin

I create a new Xamarin portable project and I'm getting

> 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Animation'

error. Any idea how may I fix it?

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Please post any versions of libraries you are using in your post. That would be versions such as Xamarin.Forms, Android Support, etc. Chances are, you simply need to update to the latest stable version of Xamarin.Forms which will update the Android Support libraries accordingly.

Comment: Ok. following are my packages:   <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.0.0.6482" targetFramework="monoandroid60"

Comment: In NuGet, update your Xamarin Forms package to the latest Stable. This will update the other packages.

Comment: <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter"

Comment: version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.0.49" targetFramework="monoandroid60"

Comment: No get both side undefined!!! I mean global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in = = global::App2Portable.Droid.Resource.Animation.abc_fade_in;

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219973/resource-contains-no-definition-for-animation/33228113#33228113 Basically the same set of solutions apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Resource" contains no Definition for "Animation"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219973/resource-contains-no-definition-for-animation)